# How do I use a image photo as a Windows phone Button

Tags: xna, windows-phone

I created a button image and I named it `Texture2D btn_play`. It is for a main menu and I want to press it to change the `CurrentGameState`.

My variables:

```
    GraphicsDeviceManager graphics;
    SpriteBatch spriteBatch;

    Texture2D Tex_Btn_play;
    Rectangle Rec_Btn_play;

    enum Menu
    {
        MainMenu,
        Playing,
        Exit,
    }

    Menu CurrentGameState = Menu.MainMenu;
```

And the `Update` method:

```
protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime)
{
    // Allows the game to exit
    if (GamePad.GetState(PlayerIndex.One).Buttons.Back == ButtonState.Pressed)
        this.Exit();

    if (Rec_Btn_play = TouchLocationState.Pressed);
    // TODO: Add your update logic here

    base.Update(gameTime);
}
```

The `if (Rec_Btn_play = TouchLocationState.Pressed);` Is wrong, I don't know why. Please help me solve this problem.

Comment: I don't understand why this question was downvoted. Is there a good reason or just because he did not know somthing someone else considers basic?

Comment: Hehe thx im srr if it a basic question is that im 17 years old and im learning thing from the internet ill start learning when I was 13.. Im trying to do my best so I can be a game company this gonna be my life :) xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to find the touch locations and check if the rectangle intersects with that position

```
TouchCollection touchCollection = TouchPanel.GetState();
foreach (TouchLocation tl in touchCollection)
{
    if (tl.State == TouchLocationState.Pressed)
    {
        if (Rct_Btn_Play.Contains(new Point(tl.Position.X,tl.Position.Y))
        {
            //DoStuff
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thxxx Cyral you was right and I read about your game too xDDD Cyral I have another problem do I make another blog for it?

Comment: No problem! Glad you saw my game. And yes, on SO here you should ask another problem if you still need assistance (Provide code, research,etc)